SharePoint Server 2019 / Subscription Edition v2.1 API
We've used SharePoint Server 2019 for quite some time, but never really used the REST APIs. Last week, we tried to access the term store via REST and experienced an exception when calling any "/_api/v2.1/" URL.
We always get this exception: Could not load file or assembly &#39;WinLive.SkyShared.Infrastructure.Utilities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6826d94a3ff89317&#39; or one of its dependencies. The located assembly&#39;s manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
We are also running a SharePoint Server Subscription Edition farm where we get the same exception.
I can find 3 WinLive DLLs on our Frontend Servers under "C:\inetpub\wwwroot..._app_bin" and under "[...]\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\BIN":

WinLive.SkyShared.Infrastructure.ServiceException.dll
WinLive.SkyShared.Infrastructure.Streams.dll
WinLive.SkyShared.Infrastructure.Utilities.dll

The Exception states, SharePoint requires version 3.0.0.0. The DLLs on our servers are 3.0.45.23381 though. I don't know what kind of assemblies these "WinLive.Skyshared.[...]" are and I cannot find any information about them.
I really don't have a clue on how to approach this. We've had similar issues when something was missing in the GAC for instance. I don't know if that relates and even if it did, I don't know I could get these DLLs in the required version.
Does anybody have any knowledge or any Tips about this (or even a solution)?
In the ULS logs we find a warning including the stack trace:
Application error when access /_vti_bin/client.svc, Error=Could not load file or assembly 'WinLive.SkyShared.Infrastructure.Utilities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6826d94a3ff89317' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)  
 at Microsoft.OneDrive.Owin.Middleware.AddDollarToQueryMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()    
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)    
 at Microsoft.OneDrive.Owin.Middleware.AddDollarToQueryMiddleware.Invoke(IOwinContext context)    
 at Microsoft.OneDrive.Owin.Middleware.MergeRequestPathMiddleware.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()    
 at Microsoft.OneDrive.Owin.Middleware.ManageSelmaScopeMiddleware.<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()    
 at Microsoft.OneDrive.Owin.Mapping.MapIfMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    
 at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    
 at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
 at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

